# How to grab title and content of web page

Tags: php, preg-match, fetch

I have a web-page, for example, `http://example.com/some-page`. If I pass this URL to my PHP function, it should grab the title and content of the page. I've tried to grab the title like this:

```
function page_title($url) {
    $page = @file_get_contents($url);
    if (preg_match('~<h1 class="page-title">(.*)<\/h1>~is', $page, $matches)) {
        return $matches[0];
    }
}

echo page_title('http://example.com/some-page');
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: You may want to try and use a DOM parser for this. Might work better than `preg_`.

Comment: http://ahoj.io/parsing-html-pages-using-xpath

Comment: Please provide the unexpected result you got, or error message. Remove the `@` with which you currently try to suppress error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function actually works almost. I would propose the DOM parser solution (see below), but before doing that I will point out a few weaknesses in the regular expression and code:

- the `(.*)` capture group is greedy, i.e. it will catch a string that is as long as possible before a closing `</h1>`, even across line breaks (because of the *s* modifier). So if your document has multiple `h1` tags it would capture up until the last one! You could fix this, by making it a lazy capture: `(.*?)`
- the actual page may have other tags, like a `span`, inside the title. You might want to improve the regular expression to exclude any tags that surround your title, but PHP has a function `strip_tags` for that purpose.
- Ensure that the file contents were actually retrieved; an error might have prevented correct retrieval, or your server might not allow such retrieval. And as you suppress errors using the `@` prefix, you will maybe miss them. I would suggest removing the `@`. You could also check the return value for *false*.
- are you sure you want the `H1` tag contents? A page has often a specific `title` tag.

The above improvements will give you this code:

```
function page_title($url) {
    $page = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($page===false) {
        echo "Failed to retrieve $url";
    }
    if (preg_match('~<h1 class="page-title">(.*?)<\/h1>~is', $page, $matches)) {
        return strip_tags($matches[0]);
    }
}
```

Although this works, you will sooner or later bump into a document that has an extra space in the `h1` tag, or has another attribute before `class`, or has more than one css style, etc... making the match fail. The following regular expression will deal with some of these problems:

```
~<h1\s+class\s*=\s*"([^" ]* )?page-title( [^"]*)?"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/h1\s*>~is
```

... but still the `class` attribute has to come before any other attributes, and its value must be enclosed in double quotes. Also that could be solved, but the regular expression will become a monster.

**The DOM way**

Regular expressions are not the ideal way to extract content from HTML. Here is an alternative function based on DOM parsing:

```
function xpage_title($url) {
    // Create a new DOM Document to hold our webpage structure
    $xml = new DOMDocument();

    // Load the url's contents into the DOM, ignore warnings
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $success = $xml->loadHTMLFile($url);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    if (!$success) {
        echo "Failed to open $url.";
        return;
    }

    // Find first h1 with class 'page-title' and return it's text contents
    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('h1') as $h1) {
        // Does it have the desired class?
        if (in_array('page-title', explode(" ", $h1->getAttribute('class')))) {
            return $h1->textContent;
        }
    }
}
```

The above could be still improved by making use of [`DOMXpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

**EDIT**

You mentioned in comments you actually don't want the contents of the `H1` tag because it contains more text than you want.

Then you could read the `title` tag and the `article` tag contents:

```
function page_title_and_content($url) {
    $page = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($page===false) {
        echo "Failed to retrieve $url";
    }
    // PHP 5.4: $result = (object) ["title" => null, "content" => null];
    $result = new stdClass();
    $result->title = null;
    $result->content = null;
    if (preg_match('~\<title\>(.*?)\<\/title\>~is', $page, $matches)) {
        $result->title = $matches[1];
    }
    if (preg_match('~<article>(.*)<\/article>~is', $page, $matches)) {
        $result->content = $matches[1];
    }
    return $result;
}

$result = page_title_and_content('http://www.example.com/example');
echo "title: " . $result->title . "<br>";
echo "content: <br>" . $result->content . "<br>";
```

The above code will return an object with two properties: *title* and *content*. Note that the *content* property will have HTML tags, with potentially images and such. If you don't want tags, then apply `strip_tags`.

Comment: great but answer is like this 2015_NOV_ALL_PEOPLE - Global Entrepreneurship Week: Does your business have what it takes?  i want only "Global Entrepreneurship Week: Does your business have what it takes?" so i think inner span <span class="current-page"> inserting

Comment: The H1 tag contains "2015_NOV_ALL_PEOPLE - ...", but in your question you said you wanted the contents of the H1 tag. If you want the title you should just read the title tag.

Comment: ok works. ask me one thing if i want to get heading and content of page then whats the Regular expressions code?

Comment: error in this line    '$result = (object) ["title" => null, "content" => null];'

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\get-cat.php on line 32   this is error

Comment: which PHP version are you using? Are you on version < 5.4?

Comment: I remove this line then code is running but also showing error

Comment: ok Thanks.one thing more, in content the image it show alt can it show image url or image?

Comment: Take the src url from the image and try if you can open the image in a new browser window. But these comments are not good for dealing with new questions. Please ask this as a new question and you will get many people looking at it.

Comment: trincot, i have one problem in php script can you help me??

Comment: The best you can do is ask a new question, because it will draw the attention of many specialists. If you want me to look at it as well, then post in these comments a link to your new question, and I will look at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760806/how-to-add-last-column-in-mysql-table
look at this