# How to Add last column in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my script code

```
$sql ="SELECT     t.Contact_Email,
                  e1.Contact_Email email1,
                  e2.Contact_Email email2,
                  e3.Contact_Email email3,
                  e4.Contact_Email email4
         FROM     (
                  SELECT e.Contact_Email FROM email1 e
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT e.Contact_Email FROM email2 e
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT e.Contact_Email FROM email3 e
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT e.Contact_Email FROM email4 e
                  ) t
        LEFT JOIN email1 e1
              ON  t.Contact_Email = e1.Contact_Email
        LEFT JOIN email2 e2
              ON  t.Contact_Email = e2.Contact_Email
        LEFT JOIN email3 e3
              ON  t.Contact_Email = e3.Contact_Email
        LEFT JOIN email4 e4
              ON  t.Contact_Email = e4.Contact_Email";

echo '<table><thead><tr><th>Email</th>';
for ($i=1;$i<5; $i++){
    echo "<th>email $i</th>";
}
echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['Contact_Email'].'</td>';
    for ($i=1;$i<5; $i++){
        echo '<td>'.(empty($row['email'.$i])?'no':'yes').'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

And the output is:

[image: Current output]

The table's odd columns represent "open" actions, and its even columns represent "click" actions. 
Now I want to add a 'Total' column at the far right.

So in picture, where the header says *email 1, email 3, email 5...* the columns represent "open" actions and where it says 
*email 2, email 4, email 6...* it represents click actions.

Now, the total should be calculated as follows:

Open actions are worth 2 points, and clicks are worth 5 points. So if there are 2 "yes" values for open actions and 3 "yes" values for 
click actions, then the total should be *2x2 + 3x5 = 19*.

That is the output I would like to have. How can I do this?

Comment: Please explain a lot more your problem. It's not clear. And show us what you tried.

Comment: ok now you understand ??

Comment: The picture just shows emails, yesses and noes. I haven't got a clue what you mean by 'Total' and those calculations with clicks and points. I'm not even sure whether you want to query something or add some scripted interaction to your HTML output.Your question doesn't make sense at all to me.

Comment: in picture where email 1,email 3,email 5... are opens
and where email 2,email 4,email 6... are clicks

Comment: i want to add new column names 'Total' in last and count opens and clicks

Comment: opens have 2 point and clicks have 5 points
so if 2 yes in opens and 3 yes in clicks
then it will be 2x2 + 3x5 = 19

Comment: Given that you have a presentation layer, I would do this completely differently (except for the subquery)

Comment: I have an idea how to handle this, but I'd like to know what the base table looks like first.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OzBIX.png
ok look at this

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Hgi.png
and that is output .. i am working on it on total column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you've posted, here's how I'd handle this.

First, I'd create an associative lookup array whose keys are the column names and whose values are the corresponding point values; it would look something like this:

```
$pointVals = array('email1' => 2, 'email2' => 5, 'email3' => 2, ... );
```

You can generate this array however you wish; I'd probably read it from a lookup table in the database. Note that this array contains only the columns for which the calculation is relevant.

Next, I would include the following code *inside* your `while` loop. `$row` is the record array returned by your call to `mysql_fetch_array()`.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  ... // existing code goes here
  $rowSum = 0;
  foreach($pointVals as $colName => $val)
  {
    if(isset($row[$colName]) && !empty($row[$colName]))
      $rowSum += $val;
  }
  ... // do stuff with $rowSum here
}
```

Having said that, I would strongly encourage you to convert from the **mysql** driver to **mysqli** or **PDO**, as **mysql** is deprecated and has been removed from PHP 7. Also, I strongly suspect your query could be simplified and improved, but I'd need to see the base table to suggest anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in your SQL. While doing so, I also noticed that you don't need the `JOINS`, it can be done with the `UNION` part only, like this:

```
SELECT    Contact_Email,
          MAX(CASE source WHEN 1 THEN Contact_Email END) as email1,
          MAX(CASE source WHEN 2 THEN Contact_Email END) as email2,
          MAX(CASE source WHEN 3 THEN Contact_Email END) as email3,
          MAX(CASE source WHEN 4 THEN Contact_Email END) as email4,
          SUM(points) as Total
FROM      (
          SELECT e.Contact_Email, 1 as source, 2 as points FROM email1 e
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT e.Contact_Email, 2 as source, 5 as points FROM email2 e
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT e.Contact_Email, 3 as source, 2 as points FROM email3 e
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT e.Contact_Email, 4 as source, 5 as points FROM email4 e
          ) t
GROUP BY  Contact_Email
```

The above query will return the same like you already had, but with the additional column that has the total. You have full control over the formula,
you could even decide that one kind of click is worth more than another.

Note that the most important change is in adding the *source* and *points* values in the inner `SELECT` statements.

I did assume that the records in table *email1* (and *email2*, ...) do not have duplicate *Contact_Email* values. If however this is the case, then either leave it like it is to also count duplicates in the Total, or do a `SELECT DISTINCT` in the inner `SELECT` statements.

Here is a simple [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e490f/2).